# Which column to index for this query?

Tags: mysql, performance, query, query-performance

```
select DISTINCT id_request,username_request
from darkhast_follower
where darkhast_follower.id_request != '9762952594' 
  AND darkhast_follower.id_request != 'null' 
  AND darkhast_follower.status !=1 
  AND NOT exists ( select *
                   from log_follow 
                   where log_follow.other_id = darkhast_follower.id_request 
                   AND log_follow.id= '9762952594') 
LIMIT 5
```

Which column should be indexed? Or what is the best query to replace this?

Comment: *which colum to be indexed??* Dependent by what part of records is selected accordingly to a separate condition... Maybe none or `id_request` in `darkhast_follower`... and `(id, other_id)` in `log_follow`. PS. Replace asterisk `*` with any literal (`1` is ok) in a subquery. PPS. LIMIT without ORDER BY will give you 5 *random* records from all matched ones...

Comment: in this query only select id_request,username_request And in log_follow  me select id,other_id

Comment: some query 1 secend and some query 20 secend

Comment: @Akina `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` makes no difference in an EXISTS subquery.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ I perform practical tests on 3 different table pairs (50k/1k, 1M/1k and 140M/2M records), all of them shows 2% difference between selecting any fieldset or NULL literal and some not-null literal, in favor of the latter.

Comment: @Akina do the tests use (NOT) `EXISTS` subqueries? Very weird if yes.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ Of course. The query was `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE [NOT] EXISTS (SELECT [* | 1 | NULL] FROM table2 WHERE (correlated) AND (non-correlated))`. The only thin thing - there was no any proper index for this query optimisation, fullscan over all tables was used.

Comment: Very weird indeed. Which version of MySQL was used?

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ Server version: 8.0.12 MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: Yeah, `EXISTS` does not care what you put in the `SELECT` -- It does a "semi-join", which means that it optimizes for finding whether _any_ row matches the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not say

```
!= 'null'
```

Instead, say

```
IS NOT NULL
```

That is, unless you are actually storing the 4 characters "null" in a `VARCHAR`?

Indexes:

```
log_follow:  INDEX(other_id, id)   -- for the subquery
darkhast_follower:   no index is useful for this query
```

The query, as you have it, will scan `darkhast_follower` until it finds 5 rows matching the all the `WHERE` clauses. In doing so, it will check `log_follow` -- This task will be a table scan (slow) if you don't have a suitable index.  Else it will be fast.

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ - Not likely.  The Optimizer usually decides that `!=` is not worth optimizing in any way.  It would be faster to avoid the index and simply scan the entire table, tossing the few that are `=`.  The Optimizer would probably use the index I suggested for `log_follow` in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

No index would be helpful in terms of `inequality`.

If you have the table of N rows and `key=val` yields the `k` rows of result, then `key!=val` yields `N-k` rows. Depending on the key's selectivity  `N-k` tends to `N`. So search on inequality is equivalent to the full table scan for all cases and can't be improved by index.